# Decrease indexPath.row?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code below that I use for catch an item inside my array:

```
int value = (int)indexPath.row;
value--;

titleLabel.text = textLabelsSection0[value];
```

Considering my array `textLabelsSection0` has 8 elements and variable `value` store the number 3, but the problem is the variable value that not store the number 3, he stores the number **18446744073709551615**, causing this error:

```
index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try nsinteger or nsnumber

Comment: @Mr.T, NSInterger same error....

Comment: why are you decrementing the value ?

Comment: how many rows are you having in your table?

Comment: Is this code in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method?

Comment: if you consider the first row, the value will be -1 which lead to indexoutofbounds exception

Comment: Yeah — 18446744073709551615 is 2^64 - 1, i.e. it's -1 in a 64-bit integer. Why do you think you have to subtract 1?

Comment: The reason for the strange number in your error message is because of an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).
Indexes of `NSArray`s are `NSUInteger`s, so the system tries to use your `int` as an `NSUInteger` even though it isn't one. Negative numbers are represented in binary using [Two's complement notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) - so underlyingly the value of an int with value -1 when treated as an unsigned integer is 18446744073709551615 which is the maximum value you can represent in a 64bit integer (all bits turned on).

Comment: so... Don't have a way to fix this and store the right number?

Comment: Don't subtract 1. Both the array index and the indexPath.row are 0 based.

Comment: @rmaddy But thats the problem i create a situation that I will need to decrease that value by one, and I need know If have a way to store the right number.

Comment: Then you need to handle the case where the indexPath.row is 0. What value do you want in this case?

Comment: And If I convert IndexPath to NSString and finally convert to int again? It works?